# Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{3^n}.$ Determine (numerically or not) the limit of the infinite series by choosing $a_n=0$ or $2$ randomly.

Tags: sequences-and-series, matlab

This is a follow up question to [Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{3^n}.$ Determine (numerically or not) the limit of the infinite series by choosing $a_n=0$ or $2$ randomly.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528161/let-sum-n-1-infty-fraca-n3n-determine-numerically-or-not-the-limi)

From that question I received help in choosing randomly from the set $\{0,2\}$. Now I'm attempting to implement the code with the sum and I'm familiar with the symsum command, but it's giving an error.

My Matlab code is:

```
r = randi([1 2],1000,1)
r(find(r==1))=0
syms n
u = symsum(r(n)/(2^(n-1)),n,1,1000)
ans
```

What's weird is if I just run,

```
u = symsum(1/(2^(n-1)),n,1,1000)
```

I get a huge number, but if I do

```
u = symsum(1/(2^(n-1)),n,1,inf)
```

it outputs the right number. Is there something I'm missing about the symsum function?

I figure what I wrote above should make sense since the indexing on the vector I make with the randi function is the same indexing on the sum. Am I even using the right function to begin with?

Thanks for any help or feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error message Matlab gives you, we have

> Indexing input must be numeric, logical or ':'.

So: No indexing with symbolic variables. If you want to evaluate it for your $r_n$, just do

> `sum(r .* 2.^(-(0:length(r)-1)'));`

That does the trick. Regarding your second question, what Matlab tells you is:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{999} \frac 1{2^k} = \frac{ 
107150860718626732094842504906000181056140481170553360744375\\ \ \ 038837035105112493612249319837881569585812759467291755314682\\\ \ \ 518714528569231404359845775746985748039345677748242309854210\\ \ \ \ \ 746050623711418779541821530464749835819412673987675591655439\\ \ \ \ \ \ 46077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069375}{535754303593133660474212524530000905280702405852766803721875\\ \ \ 194185175525562468061246599189407847929063797336458776573412\\ \ \ \ 593572642846157021799228878734928740196728388741211549271053\\ \ \ \ \ 730253118557093897709107652323749179097063369938377958277197\\ \ \ \ \ \ 3038531457285598238843271083830214915826312193418602834034688}
$$
That's not a big number, just look for the `/` in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing up the issue with the $\frac{1}{2^k}$ and with the code you presented. This might be slightly off topic, but is there any good books out there for Matlab, or does one just learn by reading the help file?

Comment: I learnt it from try and error and this (http://www-m3.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/Allgemeines/Skripten/matlab.pdf), but this is German, so I do not know if it is helpful for you.-

Comment: Ah, sadly I don't speak German, but thank you for your suggestion.